# What does resolve.extensions do in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

Here is the [official document](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html) about resolve.extensions

**resolve.extensions**

An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules. For example, in order to discover CoffeeScript files, your array should contain the string ".coffee".

Default: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js"]

IMPORTANT: Setting this option will override the default, meaning that webpack will no longer try to resolve modules using the default extensions. If you want modules that were required with their extension (e.g. require('./somefile.ext')) to be properly resolved, you must include an empty string in your array. Similarly, if you want modules that were required without extensions (e.g. require('underscore')) to be resolved to files with “.js” extensions, you must include ".js" in your array.

I am totally confused by this.

"If you want modules that were required with their extension (e.g. require('./somefile.ext')) to be properly resolved, you must include an empty string in your array."

**Why?**

"Similarly, if you want modules that were required without extensions (e.g. require('underscore')) to be resolved to files with “.js” extensions, you must include ".js" in your array."

**Why? what if I include ".js" and ".css" in the array.**

I am not clear about the behavior of resolve.extension. Please explain with example.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Webpack uses `resolve.extensions` to generate all the possible paths to the module, e.g.

```
function getPaths(module) {
    return ['', '.js', '.css'].map(ext => module + ext);
}

getPaths('./somefile'); // ['./somefile', './somefile.js', './somefile.css']

getPaths('./somefile.js'); // ['./somefile.js', './somefile.js.js', './somefile.js.css']
```

Webpack would then proceed to lookup each of those paths until it finds a file.