# Module parse failed: Unexpected token but all loaders are installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I am having trouble getting my MERN boilerplate set up. I'm still learning so the answer may be obvious but I can't find an answer for the current version of webpack, react, babel. I am getting this error when I `npm run dev`:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| ReactDOM.render(
>   <React.StrictMode>
|     <App />
|   </React.StrictMode>,

webpack 5.4.0 compiled with 1 error in 231 ms
```

Which I have figured out means that the loader is not configured; however, I have this :

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../css/index.css';
import App from '../components/App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: './client/index.js',
        // add pages here with link to the js file for each
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/preset-react'
                    ]
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mern-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "dev": "npm run webpack && nodemon --exec babel-node --bin/www",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

So, as far as I can tell I have the appropriate @babel/preset-react installed, and the correct webpack dependencies and loaders but webpack hangs with the error at <React.StrictMode>

I am struggling here and would appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: Just noticed that you have missed  ``` resolve: {
      extensions: [ '.jsx', '.js', '.json']
    } ``` in your webpack config. Helpful links https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ , https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565361/what-does-resolve-extensions-do-in-webpack

Comment: I appreciate the catch but that didn't fix my problem, and what I read says that is the resolve.extensions isn't specified then webpack uses the default, am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Thank you Dolly, I figured my problem out, turned out I hadn't saved my .babelrc file so the babel-loader wasn't loading. its what i get for coding while watching a football game LOL